# How to reset / rollback offset of Kafka consumer group to a specific hour?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper

I am fetching data from a Kafka topic using Logstash and insert it to Elasticsearch. I got corrupted data due to some configuration mistake in Logstash and I want to re consume the topic from yesterday 2 O clock. Is this possible?

Comment: What 's the version of Kafka are you using? As of 0.10, you could call KafkaConsumer#offsetsForTimes to search the expected messages if you are using Java consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [`kafka` Logstash input](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kafka) does not support the seek by timestamp feature that's been introduced in Kafka 0.10.

Suyog Rao (head of Logstash team) has been [working on a feature branch](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kafka/tree/feature/seek_by_time) to add this functionality, but last time I checked it was not yet working because of the [comment mentioned on lines 292-294](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kafka/blob/feature/seek_by_time/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb#L292-L294), i.e.

> this does not work as there are no partition assignment yet :(
>   See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2359
>   We need to call poll() and then seek which does not make sense and can lose data